# Installing portable ruby and portable xampp in order to use compass and sass in my windows machine: Is that possible?

Tags: ruby, windows, xampp, sass, compass-sass

I want to try using SASS and compass. As I´ve read that compass runs in ruby, I need to install ruby on my local windows machine in order to go and play with it.

I thought on installing everything in a portable way, I mean in my pendrive.
I´ve download a [portable ruby](http://www.yellosoft.us/portable-ruby) version and a [portable xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html#646) version, and I´ve installed both in my pendrive.

My question is: As I´ve haven´t worked with ruby ever, should I just run the ruby app and the xamp app and then just install compass in there?
I´ve read compass installing version, but I don´t know how to install it using the command line inside the pendrive.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083297/hello-world-of-sass-on-my-localhost

Comment: I´ve read carefully those comments, specially yours, and that´s why I want to install ruby on my server. As I understand I don´t need ruby on my server, but I do need it to work locally. And as I use xampp locally I just wanted to know if there´s some additional tip that I should be aware of in case I would like to use it on a portable device. Because almost all tutorials out there uses macs and not windows. For a person that is not a programmer but want to learn, and that english isn´t her first language, and it uses windows, it´s pretty difficult to understand this by herself.

Comment: You just changed your comment while I was writing mine.

Comment: And no, I don´t think is a duplicate, because my question refers to installing ruby on localhost on windows... in a portable way.

Comment: Have anyone read the compass installation instructions? http://compass-style.org/install/ There´s no first step "download the script here". So I think that´s in no way newbie friendly. 
Belive it or not, I´ve found this link https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass after googling for it. Maybe it´s in the site somewhere, but couldn´t find it.
With that kind of initial documentation, how am I suppose what to do in my first time with the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´ve found somewhere else the reply to this, and just in case anyone wonders the same thing, here´s the fastest way to use SASS when you have windows and don´t know a word about ruby, but you read that you need it in order to use compass:

1. You can install ruby in your windows pc using [this](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). I´ve tried the portable one but didn´t worked in my case.
2. After that you have to open a special console window (the one with ruby activated). There´s this icon called "start commend promt with ruby" that does exactly that. It is in the same folder as your ruby installation.
3. You just type this: gem install compass
   No, you don´t have to download nothing, it just installs the application.
4. You don´t need to use the command line anymore, nor you have to pay for the compass.app: You have the free alternative [Scout](http://mhs.github.com/scout-app/). You install it and from that moment you can work with it.

Maybe you should read these aswell:
http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass
http://andrewpwatson.com/posts/how-set-compass-sass-windows-aptana-studio-3